# SSL did'nt work with Kodi Jarvis

Tags: python, ssl, kodi

Is there any fix voor the SSL error in Kodi Jarvis? I know that it works in Kryton, but in Jarvis i have this error:

```
Error Type: <class 'urllib2.URLError'>
                                    Error Contents: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: Kodi 16.1 use Python 2.7.8.

Comment: Consider upgrade to a later version, it would work with 2.7.9, 2.7.10

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not possible to upgrade Python in Kodi 16.1.

Answer (score 0):

The site you request is possibly hosted by Cloudflare Free SSL and requires support for [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). SNI is support with Python 2.7 only since version **2.7.9.**

The SNI handshake will fail because the server does not know which certificate is requested and thus will not sent any certificate but instead an alert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle errors in Jarvis, change SSL-package (which is used in krypton) while compiling in Jarvis.

If do not want to use above steps then use requests module instead of urllib module, it will work temporarily.